# Data binding class attributes to a react component

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to find a better way to work with logic in my react components. However, not having any luck since I'm not using state here.

First some background. I have very complicated logic in my front end with a few layered recursion parameters and an n amount of parameters and a few methods in my logic class, which works great to compile and manage the logic tree of objects which attributes I want to render. Doing this with state is just to complex especially due to the recursion. Also abstracting the logic like this makes testing very simple.

So in a perfect world the flowing would be ideal:

```
import React from 'react';

class Logic {
  constructor(init) {
    this.c = init;
    this.incC = this.incC.bind(this);
  }

  incC () {
    this.c = this.c+1;
  }
}

const Test = ({logic}) => (
  <div>
    {logic.c} 
    {' '}
    <button onClick={logic.incC} type='button'>Inc</button>
  </div>
);

const Comp = () => {
  const logic = new Logic(0);
  return (<Test logic={logic} />);
};

export default Comp;
```

Of Course react one rerenders on state change and this will not work to show updates on `c`. However the method `incC` does execute.

Any idea how to map the Logic class attributes to a react component state? even if very nested like this:

```
class Logic {
  constructor(init) {
    this.tree = {a: '1', b: [{a: '2', b: [{a: '3', b: (_continues nesting_) }] }] };
  }
}
```

The other idea I'm considering in writing the object tree to apollo cache and then querying the cache where I need the attributes. But this method is a little more involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this abstraction issue using Apollo cache:

```
import React from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { useQuery , useApolloClient } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

class Logic {
  constructor(client) {
    this.client = client;

    this.c = 0;
    this.name = 'new';

    this.inc = this.inc.bind(this);
    this.setName = this.setName.bind(this);
    this.set = this.set.bind(this);
    this.set();
  }

  set() {
    this.client.writeData({
      data: {
        count: this.c,
        name: this.name
      },
    });
  }

  inc () {
    this.c = this.c+1;
    this.set();
  }

  setName (v) {
    this.name = v.target.value;
    this.set();
  }

}


const countQuery = gql`
  query getCount {
    count @client
    name @client
  }
`;

const Test = ({logic}) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(countQuery);

  if (loading) return 'Loading...';
  if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

  return (
    <div>
      {data.count}
      {' '}
      <button onClick={logic.inc} type='button'>Inc</button>
      <br />
      <input value={data.name} onChange={v=>logic.setName(v)} />
    </div>
  );
};


const App = () => {
  const client = useApolloClient();
  const logic = new Logic(client);
  return (<Test logic={logic} />);
};

export default App;
```

This is a nice example to abstract a Logic class which is easy to test from your react components using Apollo client cache.